# Boundary removal of images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to remove boundary from my image in `Matlab`.
[image]
I've tried this

```
clc,clear,clf

Im=im2double(imread('Im.png'));
imshow(Im);title('Original Image')
pause(.5)
imshow(edge(Im));title('after Sobel')
pause(.5)
imshow(Im-edge(Im));title('Im-edge(Im)')
```

and the result is

[image]

but there is two clear problem:

1. The output of the `edge` by default `Sobel` contain some inner part of shape.
2. Subtract  `binary` image from `gray scale` one!(output of `edge` is `binary`)

   any help would be appreciated.

[Download](http://www.4shared.com/photo/EWOVlQORce/Im_online.html) original image.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the boundary"? Do you mean remove the white perimeter of the object?  Your desired result at the top of your post includes edge pixels that are internal to the object, so what you are describing and your desired results don't correspond to each other.

Comment: yeah just wanna to remove white band around the shape,desired image have been shown in binary mode.

Comment: the main goal is to determine the seam in the photo. this photo is obtained after background segmentation by hough lines

Comment: @vega, this is not just for +2 pts, but if you think so, I do not spend my time correcting them anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of doing this is threshold the image so that you have a solid white object, shrink the object by a little bit. Then, use the slightly decreased object to index into the main object mask and remove this area. Also, increase the area of the intermediate result by a little bit to ensure that you remove the outer edge of the boundary.   This will ultimately produce a hollowed out mask which is designed to remove the boundaries of your object within some tolerance while leaving the rest of the image intact. Any values that are true in this mask can be used to remove the boundaries.

For reproducibility, I've uploaded your image to Stack Imgur so that we don't have to rely on a third party website to download your image:

[image]

This "little bit" for shrinking and growing you will have to play around with.  I chose 5 pixels as this seems to work.  To do the shrinking and growing, use an erosion and dilation respectively with [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) and [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) respectively and I used a structuring element of a 5 x 5 pixel square.

```
% Read from Stack Imgur directly
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcKA.png');

% Perform Sobel Edge detection
sim = edge(im, 'sobel');

% Find the mask of the object
mask = im > 5;

% Shrink the object
se = strel('square', 5);
mask_s = imerode(mask, se);

% Remove the inner boundary of the object
mask(mask_s) = false;

% Slightly enlarge now to ensure outer boundary is removed
mask = imdilate(mask, se);

% Create new image by removing the boundaries of the 
% edge image
sim(mask) = false;

% Show the result
figure; imshow(sim);
```

We now get this image:

[image]

You'll have to play around with the Sobel threshold because I actually don't know what you used to get the desired image you want.  Suffice it to say that the default threshold does not give what your expected results show.